# Subtrair campos dentro do while no PHP

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldade de subtrair campos de uma mesma coluna (medição), tenho data, hora e medição em uma tabela chamada leitura.

quero que fique assim:

```
data, hora, medicao, consumo  
06/09, 10:00, 200, 0  
07/09, 10:00, 210, 10  
08/09, 10:00, 235, 25  
09/09, 10:00, 290, 55
```

Sempre pegando a medicao do dia e subtrair com o dia anterior e informar o resultado, o campo consumo não existe no banco.

Isso tem que ser dentro do while.

```
$sqlbuscar = "SELECT data, hora, medicao FROM medicoes";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $linha["0"];  
    $linha["1"];  
    $linha["2"];  
    $consumo;     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando a medição não existe, define usando a primeira, depois mantém a que estiver definida. Depois só usar no cálculo do consumo. Mudei pouco o seu código e adicionei alguns comentários.

```
$sqlbuscar = "SELECT data, hora, medicao FROM medicoes";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$consumo = null;
$medicao = null;
while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Quando a medição não existe, define usando a primeira, depois mantém a que estiver definida
    $medicao = ($medicao ? $medicao : $linha["2"]);
    $linha["0"];  
    $linha["1"];  
    $linha["2"];  
    $consumo = ($linha["2"] - $medicao);
    // define a medição para o cálculo do consumo na próxima linha
    $medicao = $linha["2"];
    echo $consumo;    
}
```